Dapr communication issue between services on macOS in a .NET application using Aspire
I'm working on a .NET project that uses Dapr for microservice communication, running on macOS. My setup works fine on Windows, but when I try to run it on macOS, services fail to communicate with each other properly.
When I attempt to start my services with Dapr sidecars on macOS, I get the following error message when trying to communicate between the AppName-cms and AppName-api-service services:
Error: service unreachable.
I suspect this might be related to macOS Docker networking or Dapr's interaction with the Aspire framework, but I’m not sure how to debug or fix it.

Verified Docker networking is configured correctly on macOS.
Ensured that Dapr is installed and working (dapr --version).
Used a custom Dapr path in the application setup:

var builder = DistributedApplication.CreateBuilder(args)
    .AddDapr(options => options.DaprPath = "/usr/local/Cellar/dapr-cli/1.14.1");


None of these steps resolved the issue.
var builder = DistributedApplication.CreateBuilder(args)
    .AddDapr(options => options.AppId = "AppName-cms")
    .AddDapr(options => options.AppId = "AppName-api-service");


I expect the services AppName-cms and AppName-api-service to communicate with each other on macOS just as they do on Windows.

It sounds like docker-related issue, recent I found if the dockfile donwload/copy from some where will face some issue.  Try to delete docker-related files and re-add docker support in current project.
